# Does $\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]\rightarrow 1$ imply that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq A_n)\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables taking values on the non negative integers which is finite almost surely (that is, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $k=k(n)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n>k)=0$), $\varepsilon_n\in(0,1)$ and $\varepsilon_n A_n\geq O(1)$.

**Question:** Does $\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]\rightarrow 1$ imply that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq A_n)\rightarrow 0$?

The main tool i've been using to relate these expressions is Markov Inequality, but in this case i get an inequality in the wrong direction. To illustrate this, here is my reasoning on why the converse is true if $\varepsilon_nA_n=o(1)$. By the Markov Inequality,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq A_n)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_n<A_n)\geq 1- \frac{\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]}{(1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n}}.
$$
Now, as $(1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n}=[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{1/\varepsilon_n}]^{A_n\varepsilon_n}$ and $\varepsilon_n A_n=o(1)$, we have $(1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n}\rightarrow 1$, so $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq A_n)\rightarrow 0$ implies $\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]\rightarrow 1$.

I also think that the answer to my question could follow from some tail arguments in the expected value, but i'm not been able to formalize that.

Comment: My answer doesn't really go beyond Markov (rather, an "unrolled" version of it, essentially the middle step of the proof of Markov's inequality), and it seems to provide the desired statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c>0$ such that $\varepsilon_n A_n \geq c$ for all $n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]
&\leq \mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}\mathbf{1}_{X_n \geq A_n}] + \mathbb{P}\{X_n < A_n\} \\
&\leq (1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X_n \geq A_n}] + \mathbb{P}\{X_n < A_n\} \\
&= 1- \left(1- (1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n}\right)\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X_n \geq A_n\}
\end{align}$$
Now,
$
(1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n} \leq e^{-\varepsilon_n A_n} \leq e^{-c} < 1
$
so
$$
1-(1-\varepsilon_n)^{A_n} \geq 1-e^{-c} > 0
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X_n \geq A_n\} \leq (1-e^{-c})^{-1}\left(1-\mathbb{E}[(1-\varepsilon_n)^{X_n}]\right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
showing the result.

Comment: There is a nontrivial chance I messed up with some inequality, so worth double-checking...